# Django - error with FormView

Tags: django, django-views

I'm fairly new to Django. I have a form that I need to display, so I am using the FormView class. However, since I changed to using this class (I just had it as a normal function previously), I am getting an error:

`__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`

At location:

`/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 111`

The traceback is simply:

`response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)`

The relevant view is:

```
class HMFInput(FormView):
    """
    The form for input. 
    """
    template_name = 'hmfform.html'
    form_class = forms.HMFInput
    success_url = '/hmf_finder/hmf_image_page/'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        canvas, file_object = utils.hmf_output(form)
        self.request.session["canvas"] = canvas
        self.request.session["text"] = file_object
        return super(HMFInput,self).form_valid(form)
```

I tried to follow almost exactly the example from the documentation. Any idea what's going wrong?

EDIT: My `urls.py` calls the view with the following:

```
url(r'^hmf_finder/$',
    'hmf_finder.views.HMFInput',
    name = 'HMF-input'),
```

Cheers.

Comment: How are you calling this view? Are you doing so strictly from the urls.py ? Can you post how you call this view? Also, as a side note, it would be better to provide a detailed name in CamelCase for your class name.

Comment: @Esteban  - thanks very much for your quick reply! I think it is called from the `urls.py`. I will edit my post to add this information...

Comment: Hey I figured it out. Should've read the tutorial on class-based views before trying to use one. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! (See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in urls.py:

```
from finder.views import HMFInput

url(r'^hmf_finder/$', HMFInput.as_view(), name = 'HMF-input'),
```